# GGPlot Dual Axis Line Chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to generate a dual axis plot. I have successfully generated a secondary axis on the correct scale, but I cannot get both geom_lines to plot.

The code below plots the primary plot on the left axis, but the secondary plot (emp) is not displayed (or is still scaled to the primary axis so it doesn't show).

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=month, y=Amount, colour ='Expenses')) +
      geom_line() +  geom_smooth(method='lm',show.legend =TRUE, se = FALSE, aes(y=Amount,  colour='Trend'))+
      geom_line(aes(y=per_emp, colour='per_emp'))+
     geom_smooth(method='lm',show.legend =TRUE, se = FALSE,aes(y=per_emp, colour='trend'))+
      scale_y_continuous(
        # Features of the first axis
        name = "First Axis",
        # Add a second axis and specify its features
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(data$per_emp), name="Second Axis"), )+ 
      scale_colour_manual( 
        name = ("Legend"),
        values = c("Expenses" = "black", 'Trend' = 'blue', 'trend' = 'green', 'per_emp'='red'))
```

[image]

I have seen recommendations for creating a formula to set the secondary axis, so I have tried that as well, and received similar results.

```
ylim.prim <- c(0,6000000)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(0, 7000)    # in this example, temperature
    
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])
    
ggplot(data, aes(x=month, y=Amount, colour ='ex')) +
      geom_line() +  geom_smooth(method='lm',show.legend =TRUE, se = FALSE, aes(y=Amount,  colour='Trend'))+
      geom_line(aes(y=per_emp, colour='emp'))+
     geom_smooth(method='lm',show.legend =TRUE, se = FALSE,aes(y=per_emp, colour='trend'))+
      scale_y_continuous(
        # Features of the first axis
        name = "First Axis",
        # Add a second axis and specify its features
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name="Second Axis"), )+ 
      scale_colour_manual( 
        name = ("Legend"),
        values = c("ex" = "black", 'Trend' = 'blue', 'trend' = 'green', 'emp'='red'))
```

[image]

Any recommendations to get the per_emp field to plot on the secondary access, as well as the trend line for that plot?

Comment: Secondary axes are just a decoration in ggplot2; your data is always displayed vs. the primary axis, so will need to be scaled if you want it in terms of the secondary axis. It will be easier to help if you can include some example data so that each person who wants to help doesn't have to reverse engineer some to match your situation.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you. Your first sentence addresses my problem. The data points I want to plot on the secondary axis are all between $3-7k, while the primary axis is within the millions.  I realized I could scale the axis by simply doing.  `sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000, name="Second Axis"), )`. Unfortunately, that only plots a straight line as the variance in the secondary data is so minute relative to the primary axis. Transforming the data to a log scale doesn't resolve the issue either.  At this point, I saved the df to a .csv and simply imported into Tableau for this plot.

Comment: One way to handle this in ggplot2 would be to scale the secondary axis series to live in the range of the primary axis; so this could be something like `ggplot(dplyr::mutate(data, Amount = Amount * ifelse(ex == "emp", 1000,1)), ...`